# Can you be visited by more than one Noble in Splendor?

Tags: splendor

In Splendor, after you have collected enough bonuses to receive a visit from a noble, can you receive a visit from a second noble with the some of the same bonuses as the first, or do you need additional bonuses?

For example: say there are two nobles that both require 3 diamond bonuses, can you receive both nobles if you only have three diamond bonuses, or would you be required to have at least 6 diamond bonuses to receive them both (3 for each)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can, but not on the same turn.

From the rules:

> At the end of their turn, each player checks the noble tiles in
>   order to determine if they’re receiving a visit from one of them.
>   A player can be visited **if they have (at least) the quantity and
>   type of bonuses indicated on the noble tile**.

So all that matters is that you have at least 3 diamonds for a noble that requires 3 diamonds; there's no requirement to have an additional 3 for an additional noble.

And the rule limiting it to 1 noble per turn:

> If a player has enough bonuses to be visited by more than one
>   noble at the end of their turn, **that player chooses the noble to
>   be received**.